# Facing issue as 404 while Ajax call in typo3

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I am new in typo3 and used the ajaxselectlist extension but while the time usage I am facing 404 not found an error.

Below code is fetch from ajaxselectlist/Resources/Templates/OptionRecord/List.html

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var form = $('#ajaxselectlist-form');
        var selectForm = $('.ajaxFormOption');
          var controllerpath = $("#uri_hidden").val();
        var resultContainer = $('#ajaxCallResult');            
        var service = {
            ajaxCall: function (data) {
                console.log("---->"+data.serialize());
                $.ajax({
                    url: controllerpath,
                    cache: false,                        
                    data: {'uid':'1'},                        
                    success: function (result) {
                        resultContainer.html(result).fadeIn('slow');                            
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrow) {
                        resultContainer.html('Ajax request - ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrow).fadeIn('fast');
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        form.submit(function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            service.ajaxCall($(this));
        });
        selectForm.change(function () {                
            resultContainer.fadeOut('slow');
            form.submit();
        });
        selectForm.trigger('change');
    });
</script>
```

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/ty2Wx.jpg]

Comment: What is the URL that is called in the AJAX request and where is your TYPO3 base installation located?

Comment: Hi  
Please find below URL while I called the method.

URL : http://localhost:8086/typo3_7_phaseshift/index.php?id=10&tx_ajaxselectlist_selectlist%5Baction%5D=list&tx_ajaxselectlist_selectlist%5Bcontroller%5D=OptionRecord&cHash=65e57145d2c4176d44b3e1ecf78fe247&uid=1&_=1515393869321